# "vector subscript out of range" error is wrong (VS2013)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

I'm getting this error (randomly and not very often):

```
vector subscript out of range
```

The problem is that this is not the case:

[image]

Code:

```
v0 = vertices[faces.getV1(i)];
```

`i` is 1246 and the result of `faces.getV1(i)` is 920. The size of my `vertices`-vector is 1824

Can anyone tell me why Visual Studio (2013 community edition) is breaking here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you debugging a optimized build? Tooltips aren't always correct, due to stack not always in sync.

Comment: No I'm on the standard Visual Studio Debug Mode.

Comment: Are multiple threads working with the vector?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I do not think so

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that size of vector has changed after checking the condition but before stopping at the breakpoint. This may indeed happen if several threads are acessing the vector.

Comment: OK thanks. I'm trying to find out if there is another thread accessing this data. But the debugger is not very helpfull in this case :)

Comment: Open the Threads window. Debug -> Windows -> Threads

Comment: "Visual Studio Debug Mode" does not clearly mean "Debug configuration" to me. If you are debugging the Release configuration, the tooltips are frequently wrong because the variable's value only ever exists in a register. A vector will have data members stored in memory and the debugger shows those properly.

Answer (score 1):

If the debug library says you're going out of range, then you're going out of range. Somehow the debugger is getting confused about which attributes are located where in memory (or it expects it to be in a register which has been overwritten...so many ways this can happen). Thus the debugger is NOT showing you the real picture about what's going on.